# Illustrator freezes on opening SVG file

Tags: svg, freeze, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to open this SVG file in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 on a Mac:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvh3svsuyleomxp/US_states.svg.zip?dl=1

The file is not that heavy (15M uncompressed) and opens quickly on most editors. However, Illustrator takes more than 10 minutes to open it and crashes often.
How can I debug/clean the file to make sure it does not contain problems?

Comment: From a XML/SVG perspective, I can't spot anything wrong with the file. The only thing that stands out as computation-expensive is that the group directly enclosing the state outline paths has an attribute `transform="matrix(0.999776,0,0,0.999776,0,0)"` that does not change the visual result (it is almost the identity transform, 0.7px across the viewBox diagonal), but makes a complete re-computation for painting needed. Try removing that?